# Continuous animation with Angular JS and Snap SVG

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg, snap.svg

I'm trying to get smooth continuous animation using AngularJS and Snap SVG. I thought I'd solved the problem; my animations run smoothly for several hours. But I left my solution running over the weekend in Chrome, Opera, Safari and Firefox (Internet Explorer cannot run it at all). When I came into work this morning Firefox and Opera had both crashed, and the pages on Chrome and Safari had both frozen.

My animation functions are as follows:

```
        /* the centre of the hub in this drawing */
        var hubCentre = "269, 367";

        /* the time to complete an animation move */
        var moveTime = 100;

        /* the Angular module name I'm defining */ 
        var turbineApp = angular.module('spinningTurbine', []);

        /* the controller for that module */
        turbineApp.controller('turbineController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
            $scope.speed = 0;
            $scope.angle = 0;
            $scope.height = 150;

            /**
             * rotate the element with the specified tag about the hub centre location
             * to indicate the specified value.
             */
            $scope.sweep = function( tag, angle) {
                var elt = Snap(tag);

                var directive = "r" + angle + ", " + hubCentre;

                elt.animate({
                    transform: directive
                }, moveTime);
            }

            function spinner() {
                setTimeout( function() {
                    $scope.angle += parseFloat($scope.speed);
                    $scope.sweep( '#blades', $scope.angle);
                    spinner();
                }, moveTime);
            }       

            spinner();
        }]);
```

My question is, does the JavaScript setTimeout() function consume resources (e.g. stack)? Or is Snap SVG consuming resources e.g. by continuously extending the transformation path?

Ideally I want this animation to run indefinitely, so I need either to work out what is causing the browsers to crash or else recode it using a different mechanism. Does Angular JS have other mechanisms for performing a non-terminating loop?

Comment: I would probably write a directive for this also...

Answer (score 0):

Would a better option be to use `$interval()`

```
$interval(function() {
                   ... Do Cool Stuff Here
                }, moveTime);
```

You will need to inject it into your controller..